# Java Tool for SUMO upper Ontology

Tags: java, nlp, ontology

Currently there are  plenty of tools to play around with Wordnet using java

[http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/)/

Similarly are there any **Java based APIs** for **SUMO** that I can use to query....

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is an open-source project, **Sigma Knowledge Engineering Environment**, the code is in Java and can be downloaded from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sigmakee/files/